# Python3 ERROR:no module named telebot after pip installed it

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

python 3.5.2 // Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I've installed pyTelegramBotAPI to code bots for telegram using this command:

```
pip instal pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Result:

```
Collecting pyTelegramBotAPI
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyTelegramBotAPI) (1.11.0)
Collecting requests (from pyTelegramBotAPI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->pyTelegramBotAPI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->pyTelegramBotAPI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->pyTelegramBotAPI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/cc/6dd9a3869f15c2edfab863b992838277279ce92663d334df9ecf5106f5c6/idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->pyTelegramBotAPI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/cb/6965947c13a94236f6d4b8223e21beb4d576dc72e8130bd7880f600839b8/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, idna, urllib3, requests, pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Then, I imported it into my source code:

```
import telebot
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "firstBot.py", line 1, in <module>
        import telebot
    ImportError: No module named 'telebot'
```

Comment: You have to use `pip3 install`

Comment: Are you running it with `python3 firstBot.py`?

Comment: @Sean it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It mostly happens for Linux Users, because there is a preinstalled python(version 2.x) in the shell, When you install a new module or run your app with default `python`, it runs and serves by `python2.x`.
You should use `pip3` when you installing it, or run your app by `python3 app_main_file.py`